# How to Divide geo spatial Raster images into tiles and combine back into a complete image

Tags: gdal

I am reading a 2048 x 2048 image in the form of (204 x204) tiles and bilinear interpolating  them to get (819x819) tiles. Then combining several 819x819 tiles to form a 8190x8190 image.
Now as you can see in the attached image, after interpolation the image has tiled edges, Is there anything wrong with interpolation or with the way the tile is being written.

for (j = 0; j < nYsize_R; j = j + nYsize_R_1)
    {

```
    if (j == nYsize_R - (nYsize_R_1 + nYsize_R_2))
    {

        nYsize_R_1 = nYsize_R_1 + nYsize_R_2;
    }


    i2 = 0; ii = nXsize_P_1; nXsize_R_1 = temp_nXsize_R_1;
    for (i = 0; i < nXsize_R; i = i + nXsize_R_1)
    {
        if (i == nXsize_R - (nXsize_R_1 + nXsize_R_2))
        {

            nXsize_R_1 = nXsize_R_1 + nXsize_R_2;

        }
        if (i2 == nXsize_P - (nXsize_P_1 + nXsize_P_2))
        {
            ii = ii + nXsize_P_2;

        }


        poBand_MS[0]->RasterIO(GF_Read, i, j, nXsize_R_1, nYsize_R_1, poBandBlock[0], nXsize_R_1, nYsize_R_1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0)

        poBandBlockB2 = resizeBilinear(poBandBlock_padded[0], nXsize_R_1 + 1, nYsize_R_1 + 1, nXsize_P_1, nYsize_P_1);

        poBand_MS_interpolated[0]->RasterIO(GF_Write, i2, j2, ii, jj, poBandBlockB2, ii, jj, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);



        i2 = i2 + ii;



    }
    j2 = j2 + jj;
    if (j2 == nYsize_P - (nYsize_P_1 + nYsize_P_2))
    {
        jj = jj + nYsize_P_2;
    }

}
```

float* resizeBilinear(float * pixels, int w, int h, int w2, int h2) {

```
double a, b, c, d;
int x, y;
unsigned int    index;
float x_ratio = ((float)h-1) / h2;
float y_ratio = ((float)w-1) / w2;
float x_diff, y_diff, blue, red, green;
int offset = 0;
int  xx = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<w2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<h2; j++) {
        x = (float)(x_ratio * j);
        y = (float)(y_ratio * i);

        x_diff = (x_ratio * j) - x;
        y_diff = (y_ratio * i) - y;
        index = (y*(h) + x);
        a = pixels[index] ;
        b = (unsigned int)pixels[index + 1];
        c = (unsigned int)pixels[index + (h)];
        d = (unsigned int)pixels[index +( h) + 1] ;

        Buffer2[xx] = (unsigned int)(a *(1 - x_diff)*(1 - y_diff) + b * (x_diff)*(1 - y_diff) + c * (y_diff)*(1 - x_diff) + d * (y_diff)*(x_diff));
        //cout << Buffer2[xx] << endl;
        xx = xx + 1;


    }
}
return Buffer2;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Bilinear probably creates artifacts to the seams. Small tiles should have some overlap.

Comment: @user30184 Please consider adding your comments as an answer;)